# override maven dependency with local library

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-rest

In my pom.xml I want to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately this library is not being pulled because it depends on:

```
-> spring-data-rest-core 2.2.1
-> org.atteo.evo-inflector 1.2
-> org.atteo.parent 1.10
```

The last one (org.atteo.parent) has an issue fixed in 1.11 (@see: https://github.com/atteo/parent/commit/8f8db3004cb89d61b22e8348dcc4935a051b5529).

What is the best way around this issue? I already tried to hack a little around (this means manually adding the org.atteo.parent dependency to the pom in a newer version, but this is neither elegant nor does it work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to remove the "org.atteo.parent" from the dependencies, is that right? If that's the case, try this:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.atteo.parent</groupId>
      <artifactId>1.10</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had to exclude the eco-inflector dependency, now it does work. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction.